# How to find the root cause of "Workflow Designer encountered problems with your document"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, workflow

I'm getting a NRE when I try to open a workflow activities XAML file in designer. My question is how to debug this. The file is very large and hasn't been modified for years and is valid XML and works when it's actually deserialized and run.

[image]

Comment: It is best to put the log and code in text is easier to read

Comment: @RaulCacacho Yes, but unfortunately that window in Visual Studio doesn't support Edit->Copy. I tried.